# libtool: error: Failed to create '.libs'

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, libtool, mpc

I got this error while installing mpc-1.0.2 under ubuntu 16.04

First, I ran the following command():

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpc-1.0.2
```

It didn't give any error.

Then, I ran the `make` command, which gave the following error:

> make  all-recursive
>   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/mpc-1.0.2'
>   Making all in src
>   make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/mpc-1.0.2/src'
>   /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..         > -g -O2 -MT abs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/abs.Tpo -c -o abs.lo abs.c
>   libtool: compile: Failed to create `.libs'
>   Makefile:448: recipe for target 'abs.lo' failed
>   make[2]: *** [abs.lo] Error 1
>
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/mpc-1.0.2/src'
>
>   Makefile:388: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/mpc-1.0.2'
>   Makefile:298: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: **mpc** : `sudo apt install libmpc-dev` → Provides version 1.0.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmpc&searchon=names

Comment: sounds like it failed trying to make a directory? do you have write-permissions in `/usr`? (That's kind of a strange place for a source tree if it's not just something you pasted to hide your homedir/username)

Comment: @KnudLarsen I already have version 1.0.3. I'm trying to install crosstool-ng, while running './ct-ng build', I'm getting the error that it is not able to install the mpc-1.0.2 version, so I was trying to install it manually.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b thanks! problem solved, I didn't had the write permission in `/usr`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same, then I tried `sudo make` and it works.I also ran the `./configure` with              `sudo ./configure`

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [make](/questions/tagged/make) [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo)

Answer (score -1):

If your are installing it in a folder with root access then you need to use sudo with it